# Secure Remote Password Protocol SRP and Spring Security

Tags: java, security, spring-security, srp-protocol

I am trying to find more information about spring security implementation (if any) of SRP (Secure remote Password protocol) version 6 and above.  Jboss has already implementation of the this protocol.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Security_on_JBoss-The_Secure_Remote_Password_SRP_Protocol.html

Does spring also have or intend to integrate it? Is there any implementation example out there, even if using external libraries/projects but related to Spring?

Comment: Hello, maybe http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/x509.html . hope it may help in your search

Comment: Tony, have you read the page you posted yourself? I do not see any connection between SRP and X.509 except that bought are closely related to Diffie-Hellman. This is definitely not what i was looking for.